# Problem with querying database through AWS Lamda function (Node.js)

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to write a simple AWS Lamda function in nodejs to read and return data from an AWS RDS mySQL database, but the code always only returns:

```
    Response:null
```

when it is supposed to return the value 'Bbbb', which is the name of emp_id = 2 in my database.
Any help would be really appreciated!

Below is my Lamda code:

```
   var mysql = require('mysql');
   var config = require(./config.json)

   var pool = mysql.createPool({
      host: config.dbhost,
      user: config.dbuser,
      password: config.dbpassword,
      database: config.dbname,
      port: 3306
   });

   exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
     context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
     pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
       connection.query('SELECT emp_name FROM employee_info WHERE emp_id = 2', function(error, results, fields) {
       if (err) callback(error);
       callback(null,results[0].emp_name);
       connection.release();
       });
    });
};
```

Comment: can you log `results` and see if that is being logged?

Comment: You're incorrectly invoking `callback(...)` in both the error case and the non-error case.

Comment: Additionally, if your handler is async then it should return a promise. I'm not sure what the behavior will be if the handler is async and you use the callback but I would not mix them.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! It will be very helpful if you can give some suggestions to invoke the callback function correctly in this case.

Comment: Have you configured your lambda to run in a VPC?  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/

Comment: For now, remove `async`, invoke the callback once in the error case, not twice, and add some logging via console.log (log the error, log the result, etc.) Then look at CloudWatch Logs for your Lambda function. What does the logging tell you? Did the SQL query fail or succeed? Did the Lambda function complete normally or timeout? PS when responding to comments in Stack Overflow be sure to add the recipient's name otherwise they may not be notified. For example: @Mairo889